# How to center the content of an input value attribute

Tags: css, html

Is there any way to align the text whose input **value** attribute contains.
I talk about centering the text in submit button through it's value.

Here is HTML of what I tried:

```
<span id="valueAlign">
    <input formaction="mailto:rooney_09@abv.bg" onclick="" type="submit" value="Submit all" id="submit" method="post" formtarget="_blank"/>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="submit"] {padding:10px 200px 10px 10px;}
#valueAlign{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}
```

I tried but without any success..
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8tc7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use padding to set button width. Use width.

```
input[type="submit"] {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8tc7/8/

Button text is center-aligned by default, you don't have to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You've set a really wide right padding, and a small left padding, so your text is going to sit to the left hand side.

If you equalise the padding, it will be centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8tc7/4/

```
input[type="submit"] {padding:10px 100px;}
```